# Navigation to secondary route URL for routerLink attribute

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Angular supports primary routes as string attributes.

i.e.

```
<button routerlink="/path1">Click Me!</button>
```

However, when there are multiple outlets, adding a secondary route does not work:

```
<button routerlink="/path1(foo:/path2)">Click Me!</button>  <<-- does not work
```

Is there a way to make this work?

Note: I realize its possible to achieve this with:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/path1', { outlets: { foo: '/path2' } }]">Click Me!</a>
```

My question is more about whether this is possible using plain string attributes (the router framework could parse it behind the scenes).

Comment: I think you can use also [**navigateByUrl**](https://angular.io/api/router/Router/#usage-2) like this `router.navigateByUrl("/path1/foo/path2");`

Comment: hey, did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45396457/2545680) help?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem to be possible with the current implementation of the router. 
When you pass a string to a `routerLink` it gets wrapped into an array here:

```
@Directive({selector: ':not(a)[routerLink]'})
export class RouterLink {
  ...

  }

  @Input()
  set routerLink(commands: any[]|string) {
    if (commands != null) {
      this.commands = Array.isArray(commands) ? commands : [commands]; <---------------
    } else {
      this.commands = [];
    }
  }
```

And [here is](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/create_url_tree.ts#L183) the function that tries to parse the wrapped `commands` and extract outlets from it:

```
function getOutlets(commands: any[]): {[k: string]: any[]} {
  if (!(typeof commands[0] === 'object')) return {[PRIMARY_OUTLET]: commands};
  if (commands[0].outlets === undefined) return {[PRIMARY_OUTLET]: commands};
  return commands[0].outlets;
}
```

As you can see, if the value inside the wrapped `commands` is not an object - which is your case, it always defaults to `primary` outlet and uses the value as a path for this primary outlet:

```
if (!(typeof commands[0] === 'object')) return {[PRIMARY_OUTLET]: commands};
```

Comment: I investigated it long time ago and seems you're right. We can't use string in `routerLink` to navigate to `outlets` path but with array it could be done