# Can't set up routing to a named outlet in Angular

Tags: html, angular, angular-routing

I have three named router outlets as shown below.

```
...
<router-outlet name="menus"><router-outlet>
<router-outlet><router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="footer"><router-outlet>
...
```

In the markup I want to route the first one, *menus*, to a component with certain submenu junk in it as [shown in the docs](https://angular.io/guide/router).

```
<ul *ngFor="let main of menus;" 
    routerLink="[{outlets:{menus:[{{main.link}}]}}]" 
    class="nav-items">{{main.header}}
```

The error I'm getting says that:

> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '%5B%7Boutlets:%7Bmenus:%5Bsubmenu1%5D%7D%7D%5D'

Am at a loss what's wrong with the syntax. Googling my fingernails off but haven't found a **simple and crude** example of a `routerLink` version showing how to point a route in a named outlet.

**Edit:** Based on the comments and samples, I need to reformulate the code being used, still with the same error. In the markup:

```
<ul *ngFor="let main of menus;" 
    (click)="pullMenu(main.link)" 
    class="nav-items">{{main.header}}
```

Then, in TS:

```
constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

pullSubmenu(input) {
  console.log(input);
  this.router.navigate(
    [{ outlets: { menus: [input] } }], 
    { relativeTo: this.route });
}
```

Now, I'm getting the following error (*submenu1* is the name of configured path).

> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'submenu1'

My routing is set up in the module like this.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "submenu1", component: Submenu1Component },
  { path: "submenu2", component: Submenu2Component }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    MainAreaComponent,
    Submenu1Component,
    Submenu2Component
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b6mniw?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: Where do you declare `outlet` property in your router configuration?

Comment: @yurzui Nowhere, bro! That was the problem (besides a gazillion other things). I hit the spot just as you wrote your comment. Post a reply and I'll +1 you definitely!

Comment: Look at the example above. You can use navigation by using `routerLink`. You can upvote my other answer if you want:) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38038001/multiple-named-router-outlet-angular-2/38038733#38038733

Comment: @KonradViltersten, I've figured it out. Just as my other answer states you **can't** use `routerLink` if you provide commands **as a string**, but you can evaluate them and provide as array. I added that information to my answer.

Comment: @yurzui I've given it a try but got stuck on the next step. Please feel welcome to take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45765264/cant-route-to-the-primary-outlet-from-component-rendered-in-a-named-outlet) if you've got a few minutes to spare. Probably something basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the evaluated version `[routerLink]`:

```
<ul *ngFor="let main of menus;" 
    [routerLink]="[{outlets:{menus:[{{main.link}}]}}]" 
    class="nav-items">{{main.header}}
```

As an alternative you can emulate the `routerLink`. Here is the gist of what it does:

```
  @HostListener('click')
  onClick(): boolean {
    const extras = {
      skipLocationChange: attrBoolValue(this.skipLocationChange),
      replaceUrl: attrBoolValue(this.replaceUrl),
    };
    this.router.navigateByUrl(this.urlTree, extras);
    return true;
  }
```

So, here is the setup using `navigate` instead of `navigateByUrl`:

```
   @Component({
      template: `
        <ul *ngFor="let main of menus;" (click)="[{outlets:{menus:[{{main.link}}]}}])"
        class="nav-items">{{main.header}}
      `
   ...
   class MyComponent {
      constructor(router: Router, route: ActivatedRoute) {}

      navigate(commands) {
         this.router.navigate(commands, {relativeTo: this.route})
```

You can't use unevaluated version of `routerLink` because it reads commands as a string and if you have `outlets`in the commands strings don't work. See [Navigation to secondary route URL for routerLink attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45396457/2545680) to understand why.

Comment: Should the first few lines of your answer be updated as well to prevent confusion from future readers?

Comment: @DeborahK, it's correct now. When you don't use paranthesis the attribute value is evaluated as a string and this is exactly what happened to the OP

Comment: I'm reading the first sentence as saying "you can't use a routerLink". But what you are actually saying is that "hey you forgot to put the square brackets around it." I just think the wording could be misunderstood.

Comment: @DeborahK, ok, thanks, I've rephrased and moved the explanation with un evaluated `routerLink` to the bottom