# Can't route to the primary outlet from component rendered in a named outlet in Angular

Tags: angular, routes

I'm playing around with the named outlets and I noticed that the following code works, sending me to the requested page **but** only if it's outside another outlet.

```
<div routerLink="banana">Working Banana</div>
```

When the above code is part of the markup rendered inside the primary outlet, the routing occurs as supposed to. However, the same routing request done from a component that's rendered in one of the named outlets seems not to work at all.

I'm reluctant to call a bug on stuff that smarter people have done, so I'm assuming there **is** a way to route in the primary outlet when clicking a component rendered in a named outlet. But how?

For the demo of working and not working bananas see [here at StackBlitz](https://angular-75q4nu.stackblitz.io). And yes, I've googled. But it's not exactly easy to find a good key combo for this stuff...

Comment: just make it an absolute navigation by adding slash `<div routerLink="/banana">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `routerLink="banana"` performs navigation relative to the current route. While it seems that you want to navigate to `domain.com/banana` and for that you need an absolute navigation. To make it absolution navigation just add a forward slash:

```
<div routerLink="/banana">
```

Comment: Came to think of a more nested example. At this stage, you're perfectly correct - I was at *base.com/(menu:x)* wanting to navigate to *base.com/stuff(menu:x)*, so */stuff* does it. What if I'm at *base.com/a/b/c(menu:x)* and want to navigate to *base.com/a/b/c/d(menu:x)* without specifying absolute path? What if I want to navigate to *base.com/a/b(menu:x)*? And is it possible to navigate to *base.com/a/b/c/d* using the static *routerLink* version (i.e. not bracketed nor coupled to a method in the TS)? If it's too big topic for a comment, I can post a new question, of course.

Comment: yeah, I think it's better if you create another question and have a routing configuration and components with `router-outlets` templates. it's much easier to think when you see the whole picutre