# How to declare a link in HTML to a route in the default outlet retaining the route in named outlet in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, router-outlet

The following anchor's *href* will navigate to route *blopp* (rendered in the default router outlet) and *shazoo* (rendered in the router named *hazaa*).

```
<a href="blopp(hazaa:shazoo)">bloppify with shazoo</a>
```

Supposing it's been clicked, I'd like to have another anchor navigating to route *flopp* (rerendering the default outlet) but keeping the part *shazoo:hazaa* unchanged (either rerendering the named outlet or not updating the rendition at all).

It doesn't work with the below tag, since we can't be certain that the named router always will be rendering *shazoo* (since it's possible that we'll arrive at *flopp* from other places than the one mentioned in the first part.

```
<a href="flopp(hazaa:shazoo)">floppify with something</a>
```

One way to achieve that would be to [programmatically snatching the click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45758823/1525840) and use script to set a value in the router instance. However, I'd like to do that from the HTML, i.e. by something like the following pseudocode (where `inherit` means *as is, do not tamper*).

```
<a href="blopp(hazaa:inherit)">bloppify with shazoo</a>
```

Is it possible and if so how? I've found zero samples/blogs of it and named outlets haven't gain that much popularity that it's well exemplified.

Answer (score 1):

from [this link](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/angular-router-series-secondary-outlets-primer-139206595e2) you can get it using .ts -I can not find in `routerLink`a parameter to indicate the "route outlet"-

```
 <a class="nav-link" (click)="secondaryNav('chat')">Chat</a>

secondaryNav(path) {
    this.router.navigate([{ outlets: {
      sidebar: [path]
    }}]);
  }
```

I think that if it's not very popular is because generally can be solved in another way (e.g. see the updated answer) futhermore is really a "bit extrange" a direction with a parenthesis

**Update** Imagine you has a main-app

```
 <auxiliar-router></auxiliar-router>
 <router-outlet><router-outlet>
```

Our AuxiliarRouterComponent is like

```html
    <ng-container *ngIf="{auxroute:serviceRoute.route$|async} as route">
      <app-component-one *ngIf="route.auxroute=="one"></app-component-one>
      <app-component-two *ngIf="route.auxroute=="two"></app-component-two>
      <app-component-three *ngIf="route.auxroute=="three"></app-component-three>
    </ng-container>
```

```
constructor(public serviceRoute:ServiceRoute){}
```

and our ServiceRoute has a Subject

```
route$:Subject<string>=new Subject<string>();
```

Any component that in ngOnInit (or what ever) make

```
constructor(private serviceRoute:ServiceRoute){}
ngOnInit(){
  this.serviceRoute.next("one")
}
```

makes that auxiliarRouterComponent show the ComponentOne

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you explain what you mean by *a "bit extrange" a direction with a parenthesis*, please? What's *extrange*? I looed it up and got *estrange* as suggestion. However I'm not sure how that fits into your point. Also, are you saying that the syntax with parentheses in a *href* attribute is discouraged? I've thought it was the default way for Angular to handle outlets. I know how to make it work with TS code but I was curious if it was achievable with only HTML.

Comment: The "bit estrange" It's only a personal opinion, sorry if the comment confussed you